# PowerShell How do I delete file by filename that are set as dates (testeYYYYMMDD.txt)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a path on a server where FILES are created for every day in YYYYMMDD format. (20120618.TXT, etc)

example files
APP20161009.TXT
APP20161008.TXT 
APP20161110.TXT

```
$YourDirectory = "C:\Temp\"

$Threshold = ((get-date).adddays(-2))

ForEach ($FileName in $CleanupList) {
    $date = ([datetime]::ParseExact((($FileName.Name.TrimEnd(".txt")).Substring($FileName.Name.Length - 12)), "yyyyMMdd", $null))
    if ($date -lt $Threshold) {
        Remove-Item $Filename.FullName -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you seeing any error messages? If so, what are they?

Comment: remove-item -filter?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask].   Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].
 Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: -  Jerod Johnson, ok.

Comment: @JerodJohnson -  updated the code. I can delete the files. I want to adjust the code to ignore the first characters and read only the last 8 "YYYYMMDD". Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem clear if the goal is to delete directories or files. The following code assumes files since the ".txt" examples suggest that.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

$YourDirectory = ".\t"
$Threshold = (get-date).adddays(-0)
$CleanupList = Get-ChildItem -File $YourDirectory |
    Where-Object {($_.Name -match 'APP\d{8}.txt') -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $Threshold)}

if ($CleanupList -ne $null) {
    ForEach ($FileName in $CleanupList) {
        Write-Verbose $FileName
        Write-Verbose $FileName.FullName
        Remove-Item -WhatIf $FileName.FullName -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete files ".txt" , ran script, you receive error message 

Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

Comment: Did you change the ".\t" directory I used to a directory on your machine? Don't forget to change the number of AddDays().

Comment: @JorgeMiguel: `-File` requires PowerShell version 3 or higher. Unless you have _directories_ named `*.txt` (unlikely), you can just omit it.

Comment: Hi all,
I have edited the code.

I run script, does not delete file and I do not get error message.

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - Did you remove the `-WhatIf` on the `Remove-Item` line?

Comment: I did it now. Did not execute.
get error message.

Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At F:\dd.ps1:7 char:16

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - When the `-WhatIf` was used, did the correct filename to delete appear?

Comment: @lit - I tried with -Whatif and without What, I get error  

Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - I added some debugging output and showed an example of using it. Are you able to use the PowerShell ISE to set a breakpoint and single-step through the code?

Comment: @lit - The error is on the line " Remove-Item  $Filename.FullName -Force"    
The error message - Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At F:\dd.ps1:7 char:16

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - Did the Write-Verbose lines output the expected filename and full pathname to the file?

Comment: @lit - Yes, by adding (get-date) .adddays (-2) 
Now I'm getting this message here Write-Verbose : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Message' because it is null.

Comment: @lit -   Update -  I received three errors - Two messages Write-Verbose : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Message' because it is null.               A emove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.These errors were on the lines  Write-Verbose $FileName
    Write-Verbose $FileName.FullName
    Remove-Item -WhatIf $FileName.FullName -Force

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - We need to know what is in $CleanupList. I added some output before the main loop. Please run with -Verbose.

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - Ok. The $CleanupList needs to be checked to see it it is empty ($null). What do you get from this?

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - The last code posted in your question ran. However, I believe that if there are no files to be removed it will fail.

Comment: @lit -  I updated the code. I can delete the files. 

I want to adjust the code to ignore the first characters and read only the last 8 "YYYYMMDD". Can you help me.

Comment: Change the -match pattern from 'APP\d{8}.txt' to '^.*\d{8}.txt'

Comment: @lit - I was able to solve. Substring($FileName.Name.Length - 12)) . Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeMiguel - It now appears that you want to base the date threshold on the file name rather than the LastWriteDate. Also, the Substring() in the question will fail if there are not exactly three (3) characters before the date in the file name.